# are there any modern cars that use a mechanical clutch?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission

I know that it's still widely used in motorcycles but what about cars? I thought it would be easy to find out which manufacturers still produce vehicles with a cable actuated clutch but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want cars that have a cable or lever actuated clutch with no hydraulics?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define modern: My wifes 2006 Clio has a cable actuated clutch

Comment: and also depends on which country are you in. In India most of the modern day cars in budget segment still uses cable operated clutches